# pass data from selected row to view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UITableView in a popover.  When a user selects a row in the popover I am wanting it to close the popover and save some data in the cell to a variable in the parent view controller.  What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a delegate in popover's table view controller and pass the variable to it as cell data
In .h of the popover's table view controller

```
@protocol PopoverTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didSelectRow:(NSString *)cellDataString;

@end

@interface PopoverTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id<PopoverTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In the .m's didSelectRowAtIndexPath call the delegate and pass the cell data variable as

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [self.delegate didSelectRow:cellDataString];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
   [super dealloc];
   [_delegate release];
}
```

Implement it in parent view controller in .h implement the PopoverTableViewControllerDelegate as

```
@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController <PopoverTableViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cellDataString;

@end
```

and in .m implement the delegate as

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   [super dealloc];
   [_cellDataString release];
}

PopoverTableViewController *popoverTableViewController = [[[PopoverTableViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
popoverTableViewController.delegate = self;

- (void)didSelectRow:(NSString *)cellDataString
{
    self.cellDataString = cellDataString;
    [popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

In this method you handle the user selection. For passing variables between view controllers from a `UITableView` to another `ViewController` read this great tutorial from ray wenderlich : http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   ParentViewController *parent = [[ParentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParentViewController" bundle:nil];
 parent.variable = //do something you want

[self.navigationcontroller pushViewController:parent animated:YES];


}
```

Something like this... Hope this helps...